# Preventing scroll when using URI hash to identify tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, fragment-identifier

I'm using JQuery UI to make tabs in my application. I needed the tabs to be linkable (direct link that opens the page and selects the correct tab). This is done by using a hash tag/[fragmented identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). But I have a issue when the content above the tabs and inside the tabs is very long.

**When clicking the tabs, the page scrolls down to the start of the tab. This is not what I want.**

I'm using Jquery 1.7.1 and Jquery UI 1.8.16.

The javascript/Jquery code is a standard Jquery UI tabs with the addition to the event "tabsshow". This is suggested in [Changing location.hash with jquery ui tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570276/changing-location-hash-with-jquery-ui-tabs) (Stackoverflow question) and [JQuery UI Tabs: Updating URL with hash while clicking the tab](http://chwang.blogspot.com/2010/02/jquery-ui-tabs-updating-url-with-hash.html) (blog - Tech Diary by Robin)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    /**
     * Add hash to URL of the current page
     * 
     * http://chwang.blogspot.com/2010/02/jquery-ui-tabs-updating-url-with-hash.html
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570276/changing-location-hash-with-jquery-ui-tabs
     */
    $("#tabs").bind('tabsshow',function(event, ui) {
        window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
    });
});
```

The following HTML can be used to test the behavior

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div style="height: 400px;">Some other content</div>
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tab_1"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tab_100"><span>Tab 100</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tab_1000"><span>Tab 1000</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab_1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
        <table style="height: 1000px"><tr><td>Hello. This is tab 1</td></tr></table>
    </div>


    <div id="tab_100" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
        <table style="height: 1000px"><tr><td>Hello. This is tab 100.</td></tr></table>
    </div>


    <div id="tab_1000" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"><h2>Heading</h2>
        <table style="height: 1000px"><tr><td>Hello. This is tab 1000.</td></tr></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

When opening the page with the following URL, one should have tab 1 opened and not scroll down to where the tab starts. The same goes for clicking on one of the tabs.

```
file.html#tab_1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery UI Tabs Causing Screen to "Jump"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243794/jquery-ui-tabs-causing-screen-to-jump)

Comment: Not the exact same but very similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be the best method, but if you rename all of the ID's after the tabs have been created, then adding a hash with the original ID won't scroll the page. I used this method because even with javascript disabled, the hash will take the user to the correct ID. Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/KQf94/) of the code below:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    create: function(event, ui) {
        // get tab plugin data
        var tabs = $('#tabs').data('tabs'),
            // tabs.anchors contains all of the tab anchors
            links = tabs.anchors;
        // tabs.panels contains each tab
        tabs.panels.each(function(i){
            // just adding a "mod_" prefix to every ID/hash
            this.id = 'mod_' + this.id;
            links[i].hash = '#' + this.id;
        });
    }
});

/**
 * Add hash to URL of the current page
 * 
 * http://chwang.blogspot.com/2010/02/jquery-ui-tabs-updating-url-with-hash.html
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570276/changing-location-hash-with-jquery-ui-tabs
 */
$("#tabs").bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
    // remove the prefix from the ID, so we're showing the original ID in the hash
    window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash.replace('mod_', '');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned the code from @Mottie might have once worked on older versions of jQuery UI,  but this has definitely stopped working. The jQuery UI Tabs api has changed quite a bit since that was written so here is an updated version that works with at least jQuery 1.10.2

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/xsx5u5g2/

```js
var $tabs = $("#tabs");
$tabs.tabs({
  create: function(event, ui) {
    // Adjust hashes to not affect URL when clicked.
    var widget = $tabs.data("uiTabs");
    widget.panels.each(function(i){
      this.id = "uiTab_" + this.id; // Prepend a custom string to tab id.
      widget.anchors[i].hash = "#" + this.id;
      $(widget.tabs[i]).attr("aria-controls", this.id);
    });
  },
  activate: function(event, ui) {
    // Add the original "clean" tab id to the URL hash.
    window.location.hash = ui.newPanel.attr("id").replace("uiTab_", "");
  },
});
```

Comment: I made one modification to this. I don't want the ID renaming to happen on pageload/create. I want it to happen when the user first clicks on a tab. This ensures that bookmarked URLs work as normal. I split the ID renaming into a separate function, then wrapped that into a 'run only once' construct and added it as the first line inside 'activate'. http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-once

Answer (score 5):

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1. This workes nicely for me.

```
$("#tabs").tabs(); //initialize tabs
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // save current scroll position
            window.location.hash = ui.newPanel.attr('id'); // add hash to url
            $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop); // keep scroll at current position
        }
    });
});
```

[jQuery UI tabs, update url when clicking on a different tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777518/jquery-ui-tabs-update-url-when-clicking-on-a-different-tab)

Thanks to [Jeff B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179216/jeff-b) for pointing me here http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ZsUBz/44/

Comment: Works Pefectly for me as well. For jQuery version 1.12.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the window hash without scrolling the page. Here is already a question on SO - [Modifying document.location.hash without page scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling).

The changes required are:

```
$("#tabs").bind('tabsshow',function(event, ui) {
    setHashWithoutScroll(ui.tab.hash);
});
```

The `setHashWithoutScroll` function can be taken from the above mentioned link.

```
function setHashWithoutScroll(hash) {
    hash = hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
    var fx, node = $( '#' + hash );
    if ( node.length ) {
      node.attr( 'id', '' );
      fx = $( '<div></div>' )
              .css({
                  position:'absolute',
                  visibility:'hidden',
                  top: $(document).scrollTop() + 'px'
              })
              .attr( 'id', hash )
              .appendTo( document.body );
    }
    document.location.hash = hash;
    if ( node.length ) {
      fx.remove();
      node.attr( 'id', hash );
    }
}
```

The accepted answer throws an error to me - `jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier`. So I had to use this one.

Comment: That doesn't fix inbound links with "#tab-id" loading the page scrolled part-way down

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following to my javascript:

```
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    // Direct links to the tabs, e.g. /my-page#tab-id can cause browsers
    // to scroll down to half-way down the page, which is ugly. We override that here.
    // (This can cause a brief FOUC effect where the page first displays then scrolls up)
    window.scrollTop = '0';
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

In MSIE, I get a brief [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) effect as the page loads scrolled part-way-down, then flicks to the top.

In Firefox, this works fine without any visible FOUC.

In Chrome, this doesn't work at all -- see [scrollTop does not work in Chrome, nor do suggested workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246276/scrolltop-does-not-work-in-chrome-nor-do-suggested-workarounds)

Answer (score 0):

This simple method worked for me:

```
/* Prevent scroll to tab on click */
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.ui-tabs-anchor").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried @mottie solution but is not working now (2 years after).
It triggers an error: `TypeError: tabs is undefined`.

Following is an acceptable solution for me:

```
// preventing scroll
// $("#tabs li a[href^='#tab']").bind('click',function(e){ // less general but better
$("#tabs li a").bind('click',function(e){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many answers on this page, and in my mind, most are overcomplicating a simple issue.

Basically, the solution from david-thomas is the simplest and most effective. Essentially, all you want to be doing is preventing the default link behaviour on a tab link (`<a>` tag).

The same answer applies to the bootstrap tabs, where you have to specify the click handler

```
   $('.nav-tabs a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your insightful and helpful comment. I am sorry my answer made your application topple from its lofty heights...