# How to disable hash changes in jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'd like to use jquery ui tabs plugin, but not have it changing the url hash when I click a tab.

I'm using a separate plugin for managing history, and it's screwing with it.

In other words, when I click a tab the content should change, but not the url hash

Any ideas?

The Docs are [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), but it doesn't mention anything about this.

Edit : Thats weird, I'm not sure what was causing it to change the window hash. It's not occurring anymore though.

Comment: I don't notice any hash changes when using the example tab setups at the documentation site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/default.html

The url hash doesn't change for me. What plugin are you using for managing history?

Comment: I'm using a custom plugin that listens for the window.hashchange event. But it doesn't interfere with anchors.

Answer (score 3):

Having the same problem. Here you go!

```
// Prevent hashtag change on tab link click
$('.ui-tabs-nav a').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: If this does not help, try adding "e.stopPropagation();" into the handler. It solved my problem.

Comment: This did not work for me but it lead me to this which did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624531/preventing-scroll-when-using-uri-hash-to-identify-tab. There are a couple solutions there. One worked for me.

Comment: 10 years later it doesn't work? Not totally surprised :D

Answer (score 0):

can you please try:

```
var currentHash = top.location.hash;

$('#example').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
   top.location.hash = currentHash;
}
```

i haven't tried it, i can't set up the environment here. It is possible that when you reset the hash, it doesn't behave as you wish...

Comment: that would wipe out the hash every time.

Comment: ok, sorry, i didn't understand your question fully. i will edit the anwer