# changing the active tab via the url in jquery ui tabs (jquery 1.10.2)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have seen versions of this question asked but they were asked about older versions of jquery or tabs that weren't part of jquery ui 1.10.2

**My question is:**
 what jquery code do I need to add to this so that 

a) the active tab's selector will be added to the url (for example, if tabs-6 is the active clicked tab, the url displayed in the browser is page2.html#tabs-6)

b) I can build links that will change which tab is active based on the url (so if I make a link on "page1.html" that points to "page2.html#tabs-3" "#tabs-3" will become the active tab?

I have consolidated several pages of a website into jquery ui tabs (using themerolled jquery UI 1.10) and I need to be able to link to the individual tabs from a menu on the homepage. I'm quite experienced with html/css, but my jquery knowledge is basically limited to being able to implement & edit demo examples.

For our purposes, the tabs chunk of the code is basically stock jquery ui from the tabs demo.

```
<head>
<script>
$(function() {

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    // Hover states on the static widgets
    $( "#dialog-link, #icons li" ).hover(
        function() {
            $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
        },
        function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
        }
    );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Tab Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-5">Tab Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-6">Tab Six</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="tabs-1">
  <p>tab 1 content</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
  <p>tab 2 content</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
  <p>tab 3 content</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-4">
  <p>tab 4 content</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-5">
  <p>tab 5 content</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-6">
  <p>tab 6 content</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

For (a) -- you'll have to write some custom code on the "select" event, I think

For (b) -- inbound links should work fine, just use the tab's div ID as the fragment (but careful about [Preventing scroll when using URI hash to identify tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624531/preventing-scroll-when-using-uri-hash-to-identify-tab) )